# pyqt5で矢印をショートカットキーに使いたい

Tags: python, python3, pyqt5

pyqt5で矢印キーをショートカットキーに使いたいです。次は試しに書いてみたコードです。

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):      

        btn1 = QPushButton("Button 1",self)
        #btn1 = QPushButton(QFont("Button 1",20), self)
        #btn1.setFont(QFont("Button 1",15))
        btn1.move(30, 50)
        btn1.setShortcut("Ctrl+W")

        btn2 = QPushButton("Button 2", self)
        btn2.move(150, 50)
        btn2.setShortcut("<KeyPress-Right>")

        # クリックされたらbuttonClickedの呼び出し
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)            
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        self.statusBar()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event sender')
        self.show()


    def buttonClicked(self):

        # ステータスバーへメッセージの表示
        sender = self.sender()
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text() + ' was pressed')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

これを実行すると次のようなGUIが作成されます。ボタンを押すと下のテキストが変わります。
[image: 画像]
ここで、btn2のショートカットキーを右矢印になるように書いてみたつもりでしたが、右矢印を押しても実行されません。どのように描けばよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setShortCut`の引数に`Qt.Key_Right`を指定すると期待通りの動作をすると思います。
いかがでしょうか?

```
    btn2.setShortcut(Qt.Key_Right)
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！左右の矢印でしっかり動作してくれました！